# OSPermissionSubscriptionState : Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal, android-push-notification

I'm trying to add push notification to my mobile native chat app. I'm trying to use OneSignal.

I can send manual push notification, so I think gradle part is okay

idsAvaiable method is deprecated, I started to looking for how can I get userId.

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
    String userId = status.getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();
```

In here, I'm trying to get userId with status, but it's saying:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'OSPermissionSubscriptionState'

How can I get userId?

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**

From OneSignal API `4.0.0`, there are many APIs that have been removed including `OSPermissionSubscriptionState`.

**Solution 1**

Use [OneSignal.getDeviceState()](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/40-api-android-native#getdevicestate--method)

```
OSDeviceState device = OneSignal.getDeviceState();
String userId = device.getUserId();
```

**Solution 2**

Use [OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver()](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#addsubscriptionobserver)

```
OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(new OSSubscriptionObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges) {
        if (!stateChanges.getFrom().isSubscribed() && stateChanges.getTo().isSubscribed()) {
            // Get user id
            String userId = stateChanges.getTo().getUserId();
        }
    }
});
```

For more information, see the change log [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/40-api-android-native).